# Backbone model is not updated from subview

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pass-by-reference

I have a backbone view that is a child view of a parent view.

```
App.Views.InvoiceFields = App.Views.baseView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "invoicedateToModel", "invoicenumberToModel");
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$el.find('[data-role="invoicedate"]').datepicker({
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            todayHighlight: true,
            language: Application_language
        });

        if (self.model.has('invoicedate')) {
            self.setInvoiceDate();
        }
        if (self.model.has('invoicenumber')) {
            self.setInvoiceNumber();
        }
        return self;
    },

    events: {
        'change input[name="invoicedate"]' : 'invoicedateToModel',
        'change input[name="invoicenumber"]' : 'invoicenumberToModel'
    },

    invoicedateToModel: function() {
        var invoicedate = this.$el.find('[data-role="invoicedate"]').val();
        this.model.set('invoicedate', invoicedate);
    },

    setInvoiceDate: function() {
        this.$el.find('[data-role="invoicedate"]').val(this.model.get('invoicedate'));
    },

    invoicenumberToModel: function() {
        var invoicenumber = this.$el.find('[data-role="invoicenumber"]').val();
        this.model.set('invoicenumber', invoicenumber);
    },

    setInvoiceNumber: function() {
        this.$el.find('[data-role="invoicenumber"]').val(this.model.get('invoicenumber'));
    }
});
```

I call it on the appropriate element, using the parent model:

```
var model = this.model;
var $invoicefields = this.$el.find('[data-role="invoice"]');
var invoiceFields = new App.Views.InvoiceFields({
    model: model,
    el: $invoicefields
});
```

The problem is that although everything works, and the data is saved to the model in the subview, when I call save() on the model in the parent view, the two attributes 'invoicedate' and 'invoicenumber' are empty once again. It's as if the model was being passed by value.

Comment: can you show the `save()` code you are using.

Comment: Well I can, but I console.log()-ed the model before saving, and that is where I saw that the attributes were already missing.

Comment: this is when you save the second time right ? value are there for the first time and missing when you save the second time. Is this right ?

Comment: I only save once. In my subview I set() the values, and when the user clicks save in the parent view, I save() the model.

Comment: Please, provide a fiddle with all relevants parts of your code. Are you sure they are using the same model?